# Can't change owner (user or group) of directory which I have all rights on?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chown

TL;DR: Why am I getting the Operation not permitted? And how can I resolve this?

---

I'm facing a problem which I can't resolve. I'm creating a directory as user a:group a), which I want to change to user b:group a. I don't understand why this operation is not permitted. This is what's happening:

```
user a@foo:~$ mkdir /home/user b/foo/test             
uber a@foo:~$ chmod 0777 /home/user b/foo/test
user a@foo:~$ ls -alF /home/user b/foo/ | grep test
drwxrwxrwx 2 user a            group a 4096 Jan  6 19:53 test/
user a@foo:~$ chown user b:group a /home/user b/foo/test
chown: changing ownership of `/home/user b/foo/test': Operation not permitted
```

(I changed the user and group names for simplicity's sake)

Other things that might be relevant:

- User A is in Group A and Group B.
- User B is in Group B.
- Directory foo in /home/user b has 0750, and is owned to User B:Group A.

I'm eager to understand as why this operation is not permitted, and how I can resolve this (a solution without using sudo is a plus)?

Comment: try sudo before your chown command

Comment: What are the permissions of the "foo" folder?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can only change ownership on a file if you're root (or have the CAP_CHOWN Posix capability). This is so because giving away files would trigger some security concerns (for example, if disks quotas were enabled you could then fill user b quota).

Use sudo chown if you're allowed to do so and it will work.

You can however change the owning group to a group you're a member of, so you should be able to chgrp "group b" "/home/user b/foo/test", which may be an alternative to share files with user b without becoming root, depending of what you're trying to achieve.

For more flexible permissions, you may want to look into ACLs.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. For now, I went with `sudo` for a very small subset of commands. I'm going to look at chgrp.

Comment: Nope, the following does not work for me: `You can however change the owning group to a group you're a member of, so you should be able to chgrp "group b" "/home/user b/foo/test"` -- the same "operation is not permitted" problem.

Comment: Frustrating... I'm having the same problem as I see people like @Ayrat pointing out for years back, where the provided "answers" still give the same "operation is not permitted" problem, even with sudo, and never with any responses.

Answer (score 0):

Part A:
The operation is not permitted because only the owner and root (TBOMK).

Part B:
The answer is now obvious. Either have user b do it, or perhaps you will have to bite the bullet and use sudo. If you don't want to use sudo I assume it is because you don't have root and will have to get someone else to do it, but those appear to be the only two solutions.